# Storing the state of the flow in Spring web-flow

Tags: java, spring, workflow, spring-webflow

I have this requirement for web-application wherein a user submits application for certain benefits by entering a set of his personal information. Every user application has an 'AppId'. So lets say a user with AppId 123 is within a flow and exits at a particular state. Next time when he logs in with AppId 123, he should be able to continue from where he left. 
How can we implement using Spring web-flow 2.3? Does SWF 2.3 has some sort of its own database like lets say a jBPM has?

Answer (score 2):

[Spring Webflow](http://projects.spring.io/spring-webflow/) isn't intended to be a workflow management or BPM system. It was designed to make it easier to work with and create complex wizard like forms. Instead of trying to shoehorn SWF into your requirements I would suggest using a proper BPM engine like [Activiti](http://www.activiti.org/) for that purpose.

However if you really want to try and shoehorn SWF into your needs I would suggest starting to study [the API of SWF](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/javadoc-api/). Which at some point will lead you to the `ConversationManager` (by default a `SessionBindingConversationManager`) which you could replace with your own custom implementation.

Comment: Thanx for the quick reply.The application we have is a web application with a well defined flow.We wish to implement conditional flow, saving the state of the flow for the user to be able to continue from where he left and having a flexible flow management.It is not really a BPM requirement and that is why using SWF seemed a better option than other tools as it integrates web applications nicely.

About our requirement, from my research for the past few days, I understand I would have to implement a custom DB based Conversation Manager. Any guidelines/resources for that would help

Comment: Hey..need to implement a custom conversation manager to persist the state of flow in db. How to I go about it? Can anyone provide a step by step guide please?