# Can Spring Web Flow Work in Non Spring MVC application?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, model-view-controller, spring-webflow

I am working on evaluating Spring Web Flow for handling conversational flows in the web application that is currently used. Currently, the web application that we are using using is a **custom company** made MVC framework that was developed 10+ years back when there was no Spring MVC or Struts etc. There is a ControllerServlet in the application which is currently doing the work of managing the requests, similar to DispatcherServlet of Spring MVC.

Now, we want to take advantage of the Spring Web Flow features and renew the application and ease the developers life. I would like to know from all you people out here who had similar experiences in the past of migrating legacy MVC application to Spring Web Flow.

Please suggest the configurations and / or changes which I should be looking at to take this into right direction.

Some of the questions which come naturally to my mind are:

1. Configuration changes to web.xml? or adding a spring related xml file?
2. Any changes that we need to make to the JSP's? I am assuming Spring Web Flow will require me to make changes in the JSP's. What do you guys feel?
3. How could we get rid of the ControllerServlet? or better yet ask the ControllerServlet to refer to Spring Web-Flow for all the requests?
4. If Spring Web Flow is replacing the ControllerServlet, what happens to all the code that is written in it? what equivalenet of Spring Web Flow do we need to write?

Thanks,
Yogendra

Answer (score 2):

Why replace, you can perfectly use Spring Web Flow (and/or Spring MVC for that matter) alongside your own MVC framework. You only have to be careful when you are crossing boundaries between the 2.

What we did in such a scenario was introduce a `DispatcherServlet` for only handling the Spring Web Flow request and everything else was handled as before. So you basically have 2 servlets instead of 1.

Another solution would/could be to replace your own servlet with a `DispatcherServlet` and let all requests for the old part of the application delegate to your own `ControllerServlet`, for this you could use the `ServletWrappingController` of Spring MVC.

Benefit of the last approach is that you could create a `HandlerInterceptor` which could move some stuff around from your own MVC framework to SWF and vice-versa.

In each and every car you would need to change the pages that use Spring Web Flow to use the Spring tag libraries so that form can be properly handled, for pages that aren't used/served by Spring Web Flow everything can remain the same.

Comment: Thanks for the initial direction. Actually I just found out that there are more then 15 controllers in the application! One controller for one module / functionality.. Now, the thing is, we are trying to get rid of the older architecture and migrate everything to SWF. So one of my question was to understand what will happen to the code written in those 15+ controllers? The JSP's that are currently written have a lot of Custom Tag codes, do you think we will have to modify all of those JSP's to support SWF? Is there a  safer route to this migration like doing it in phases?

Comment: As mentioned you can perfectly use Spring Web Flow alongside your own infrastructure. This should give you a migration path and move functionality to Spring MVC/Web Flow as you move along. It is hard to say what happens to your custom tag library, depending on what is in there you either have to replace it with the use of Spring MVC tags or migrate your tags to use the Spring infrastructure. I would say that moving everything at once would be to big a challenge and you probably want to do it on controller per controller (or wizard per wizard) basis.

Comment: Deinum, I have one more query which is exactly as mentioned in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379010/storing-the-state-of-the-flow-in-spring-web-flow. I have a web application in which there is a option like "Goto the Last Visited Page for this App Id", what we want is, the user should be able to go to the page where the user left before being logged out.

I have tried searching a lot in Spring official documentation, but unable to find any example implementations. Will you be able to help on with a sample to save the flow conversation in DB and Retreive back?

Comment: All that I see everywhere is pointers like "Use Conversation Manager for this"  or "You need to save the whole conversation to the database" without anyone pointing to the real example of how its done! I am really new to Spring Web Flow and dont understand this much. I am hoping as you are the Author of the book, I am sure you can help out with a trivial example to achieve this.

Thanks,

Comment: What is it you don't understand, implement the `ConversationManager`. It is an interface just implement it and instead of storing the object in the session store it in the database. You might need to do some trickery with BLOB fields (for object serialization). I don't really see the hard part. Create implementation, use `JdbcTemplate` to store the object in the database based on the conversation id. You probably need another means of creating a conversationId also (this should now be unique for your application instead of the session).

Comment: So the part where I am most confused is how do you store the _flowExecutionUrl in the database? Because, I am assuming _flowExecutionUrl is the only way to return to the flow from database. correct?  ConversationManager has a method beginConversation which takes conversationParameters, what are these parameters that I would need to set? conversationId is something that I have created in the app using UUID so it will be unique for all flows. but what other attributes form part of the conversationParameters?

Comment: Deinum, can you please suggest?